# Input range strange behavior when changing width via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, range

I have a group of sliders, they can all take a value from 0 to 100. I need the total of the group to always be less than 100 as they are percentages. I use the max attribute and some simple math to prevent the total from surpassing this.
Originally I just changed the max value, however, this doesn't change the length of the slider just what value all the way right is. This would be confusing to the user as 50% of the bar could be all the way right when it used to be in the middle.

To combat this I used a container div and change the slider's width to the corresponding percentage of the containing div.

This works as intended, but the slider handle slightly moves whenever you change a sibling slider.

Is there a way to prevent these small movements.

Is there a completely different easier way to do this seemly simple task, using only pure js.

```html
    <form id="form">
        <input id="incm" type="number" value="1000"/>
        <ul>
            <li>Slider 0
                <div class="sliderContainer"><input class="slider" id="pct0" type="range" min="0" max="100" value = "50"/></div>
                <output id="pctOutput0"></output>
                <output id="amtOutput0"></output>
                </li>

            <li>Slider 1
                    <div class="sliderContainer"><input class="slider" id="pct1" type="range" min="0" max="100" value = "50"/></div>
                    <output id="pctOutput1"></output>
                    <output id="amtOutput1"></output>
                    </li>

            <li>Slider 2
                    <div class="sliderContainer"><input class="slider" id="pct2" type="range" min="0" max="100" value = "0"/></div>
                    <output id="pctOutput2"></output>
                    <output id="amtOutput2"></output>
                    </li>

            <li>Slider 3
                    <div class="sliderContainer"><input class="slider" id="pct3" type="range" min="0" max="100" value = "0"/></div>
                    <output id="pctOutput3"></output>
                    <output id="amtOutput3"></output>
                    </li>

            <li>Slider 4
                    <div class="sliderContainer"><input class="slider" id="pct4" type="range" min="0" max="100" value = "0"/></div>
                    <output id="pctOutput4"></output>
                    <output id="amtOutput4"></output>
                    </li>
            </ul>


            <p><output id="pctSum"></output><output id="amtSum"></output></p>
        </form>
```

```
function calc() {

  var pct = [],
      pctI = [],
      amt = [],
      incm = document.getElementById("incm").value

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    pct[i] = document.getElementById("pct" + i).value
    document.getElementById("pctOutput" + i).innerHTML = pct[i] + "%"
    pctI[i] = parseInt(pct[i])

    amt[i] = pctI[i] * 0.01 * incm
    document.getElementById("amtOutput" + i).innerHTML = "£" + amt[i]
  }

  var pctSum = pctI.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
  var amtSum = amt.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)

  document.getElementById("pctSum").innerHTML = "Total Percentage " + pctSum + "%"
  document.getElementById("amtSum").innerHTML = "Total Amount £" + amtSum

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    document.getElementById("pct" + i).max = 100 - pctSum + pctI[i]

    document.getElementById("pct" + i).style.width = document.getElementById("pct" + i).max + "%"
  }
}

document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("input", calc)
window.onload = calc()
```

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Zbedjajohnson/ca5b1psy/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really interesting question. Here's what I've come up with.

```js
function initSliderGroups() {
  const sliderGroups = document.querySelectorAll(".sliderGroup");

  for (let sliderGroup of sliderGroups) {
    const sliders = [...sliderGroup.querySelectorAll(".slider")];
    const max = sliderGroup.getAttribute('max');
    sliders.forEach(slider => {
      slider.max = max;
      slider.min = 0;

      const sliderContainer = document.createElement('span');
      sliderContainer.style = 'position: relative;';
      slider.parentNode.insertBefore(sliderContainer, slider);
      sliderContainer.appendChild(slider);

      const limitDiv = document.createElement('div');
      limitDiv.className = 'limitDiv';
      limitDiv.style = 'position: absolute; top: 4px; left: 0; z-index: 1; width: 0; height: 5px; background-color: #555; border-radius: 5px;';
      sliderContainer.appendChild(limitDiv);

      slider.addEventListener("input", () => onSliderInput(slider));
    });
    
    function onSliderInput(movingSlider) {
      //limit sum of values to max (defined as 100 by .sliderGroup div attribute)
      const usedByOthers = sliders.filter(s => s !== movingSlider).map(s => +s.value).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
      const available = max - usedByOthers;
      if (movingSlider.value > available) movingSlider.value = available;

      //update limit bars
      for (let slider of sliders) {
        const limitDiv = slider.parentNode.querySelector('.limitDiv');

        const usedByOthers = sliders.filter(s => s !== slider).map(s => +s.value).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
        const available = max - usedByOthers;

        const sliderWidth = slider.clientWidth + 1;
        const leftOffset = sliderWidth * (available / max);
        const width = sliderWidth - leftOffset;
        const extraOffset = 17 * (max - available) / max;
        limitDiv.style.left = Math.min(leftOffset + extraOffset, sliderWidth) + 'px';
        limitDiv.style.width = Math.max(width - extraOffset, 0) + 'px';
      }
    }
    
    //init
    if (sliders[0]) onSliderInput(sliders[0]);
  }
}

initSliderGroups();
```

```html
<div class="sliderGroup" max="100">
  <input class="slider" type="range" value="25" /><br/>
  <input class="slider" type="range" value="0" /><br/>
  <input class="slider" type="range" value="0" /><br/>
  <input class="slider" type="range" value="0" /><br/>
</div>
```

Basically you just give all your slider inputs `class="slider"`, wrap them in an element with `class="sliderGroup" max="100"`, then call `initSliderGroups()` and it'll limit those sliders to a max combined value of 100 (and shows dark grey limit bars).

In your case you'd do the following:

- Add `class="sliderGroup" max="100"` to your `<ul>`.
- Add my javascript above your javascript.
- Delete your for loop in `calc` that changes `max` and `width` of sliders.

Comment: I think this will be my accepted solution. Was a bit difficult to follow with my beginner knowledge of JS, however, after reading through some documentation on; for let of loops, rest parameters and arrow functions it made much more sense. The code integrates really nicely with my current project and allows me to resize the slider with css only. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey, @ZBedjaJohnson. Glad to hear you like my solution and that you took the trouble to read through the solution even though it required learning some new stuff about JS. I was playing around with it and I found a visual issue with my solution that show up in other browsers (besides chrome). I'll try to fix that later today if I have time. Do you know which browsers you need to support?

Comment: Browser support isn't really an issue for this project as it will only be used by me, it would be nice to see what the issue is however so I could prevent it for future public projects where compatibility would be a concern.

Comment: Try it in firefox and you'll see the grey limit bars aren't aligned correctly over the slider (it's offset a few pixels down and a couple pixels to the left). Looks pretty bad but still fully functional. In safari the limit bars don't show up at all but again still fully functional.

Comment: I was seeing that offset on chrome for some reason. I added a little temporary css which seemed to fix those issues. works in chrome, firefox and edge (thumb slider needs to be reset). I can link you to my site if u would like to see.